# excerpt() shows different result between remote and localhost(development environment)

Tags: theme-development, themes, excerpt

Something strange when I am developing my own theme.

Not sure what have I changed recently, but the `the_excerpt()` or `get_the_excerpt()` started to show full text on my localhost dev environment, while on my web (actual working website online) it looks just fine, showing excerpts with "more".

I compared and pull my files from my web server to local computer, still, `the_excerpt()` shows full text instead of `excerpt.

So what else should I look into? What might have caused the localhost server to suddenly ignores `the_excerpt()` and shows full text instead(as it did on remote server online)? The files should be the same.

```
<div class="entry-excerpt">
<?php
        $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
        if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
            echo $my_excerpt; 
        };
?>
</div>
```

In localhost the above code prints full content of the post instead of excerpt.

In remote server however, the same code prints the excerpts correctly with a "more" button.

Comment: It sounds like it might be showing you an error message instead, can we see the full message? And the code in question?

Comment: I have edited the post to show you the code. it's simple code really. I am not getting any error messages, nor any errors show up in the console. In localhost it simply prints full content instead of just the excerpt (behaving like `the_content()`). I also tried `the_excerpt()` instead and the result was still the same. That said, it behaves normally on a remote server online.

Comment: and you're absolutely sure the two environments are running identical code? With the same settings in WP Admin? There's nothing environment based that would do this

Comment: As an aside, is there a particular reason you didn't use `the_excerpt()`?

Comment: yea the code are the same. i pull all the files from server(including function.php and all) to localhost and still get the same result.  I am not sure what in the admin panel could have changed that since I shouldn't have make any changes at all. I didn't use `the_excerpt()` because my theme's base file was generated from https://underscores.me/ and I leave it as is since that might be best practice considering it was developed by the guys who made wordpress.

Comment: one thing, the admin panel is running different language between localhost and remote server side, will this be the reason?